# Convert Rcpp::List to C++ vector of vectors of const char*

Tags: c++11, vector, rcpp

I'm trying to build an Rcpp interface to an existing C++ library that uses `const char*` for strings. I think I need to use Rcpp::List to pass some output indices, which is a ragged 2D array of strings. But I am having trouble converting this to the C++ primitives required by the external function.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(Rcpp::List IndexList){

      // convert list to this
      const std::vector<std::vector<const char*>> Indexes;
      for (int i = 0; i < IndexList.size(); i++){
          Rcpp::StringVector temp = IndexList[i];
          std::vector<const char*> temp2;
          temp2.clear();
          for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++){
            Rcpp::Rcout << temp[j];
            temp2.push_back(temp[j]);
          }
          Indexes.push_back(temp2);
      }
}

/*** R

test(list(c("a", "b"), c("cde")))

*/
```

The line `Indexes.push_back(temp2);` throws an error which ever way I try to build this object (which I need to pass to another function).

```
Line 19 passing 'const std::vector<std::vector<const char*> >' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<const char*>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<const char*> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<const char*>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

## Solution

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// function that wants this data structure
void feedme(const std::vector<std::vector<const char *>> &Indexes){

    Rcpp::Rcout << " feedme ";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Indexes.size(); i++){
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < Indexes[i].size(); j++){
            Rcpp::Rcout << Indexes[i][j];
        }
    }

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(Rcpp::List IndexList){

      // convert list to this
    Rcpp::Rcout << " test ";
    std::vector<std::vector<const char*>> Indexes;
      for (int i = 0; i < IndexList.size(); i++){
          Rcpp::StringVector temp = IndexList[i];
          std::vector<const char*> temp2;
          temp2.clear();
          for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++){
            Rcpp::Rcout << temp[j];
            temp2.push_back(temp[j]);
          }
          Indexes.push_back(temp2);
      }

      feedme(Indexes);

}


/*** R

test(list(c("a", "b"), c("cde")))

*/
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  The code snippet is not self contained and minimal. And we have no idea what line 108 is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `Indexes` as `const` but try to change it later on:

```cpp
      const std::vector<std::vector<const char*>> Indexes;
//    ^^^^^
// [...]      
          Indexes.push_back(temp2);
```

Remove the `const` qualifier to get the code compiled.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks. It's a while since I touched C++ and I'm not clear on the details of how things work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps.  Here we pass from of a `Rcpp::StringVector` to *two* vectors of both `const char *` and `char *`.  I was half-expecting to have to const-cast but it just built as is.

Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

void consumeConstChar(std::vector<const char*> v) {
  for (auto s : v) Rcpp::Rcout << s << std::endl;
}

void consumeChar(std::vector<char*> v) {
  for (auto s : v) Rcpp::Rcout << s << std::endl;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void doStuff(Rcpp::StringVector x) {
  std::vector<const char*> vcc;
  std::vector<char*> vc;
  for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++) {
    vcc.push_back(x[i]);
    vc.push_back(x[i]);
  }
  consumeConstChar(vcc);
  consumeChar(vc);
}

/*** R
x <- c("The quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped")
doStuff(x)
*/
```

Demo

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/58741017/answer.cpp")

R> x <- c("The quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped")

R> doStuff(x)
The quick
brown
fox
jumped
The quick
brown
fox
jumped
R>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it working for the StringVector, it's the List I'm having trouble with. I'll post a reprex now.